# How can I keep the text format the same way it was captured in the django admin

Tags: django, html, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would to know if its possible to render the text in the template and keep the same text format as the text was captured in the admin. I've attached a picture of my problem. As can be seem in picture below. The text is formatted in paragraphs and sometimes there is some bold text, the problem is that when the text is render to the template, all the formatting is removed.[image]

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: How do you render this in your template?

Comment: At first sight, it looks like you `marked_safe`d it somewhere, since by default Django does escape the content.

Comment: this is how I render the text, {{ tender.description }}

Comment: But you do not render it directly (in static HTML)? Since the quotation marks do not show up as well.

Comment: So, you are talking about that the formatting is removed when seen from the template? Remember, Django by default escape all the characters.

Comment: Do you use Ckeditor in your model ? if so {{ tender.description|safe }} did you try it ?

Comment: I created a custom tag that replaces the '\n' with <br> in the text but the browser does not render the <br> tags, instead it just displays them. (i.e. {{ tender.description|html_formatter:"0" }})